# Macbook Pro low battery warning to instant recharge

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, battery

My Macbook Pro (Mid 2012, OSX 10.10.2) sometimes gives the `Low Battery` warning, then immediately after dismissing the notification the battery pops back up to about 25% battery, still showing a red battery icon.

[image: It is above 20% but is still red.]

**It is above 20% but is still red.**

*What could have caused this, is it an error in Yosemite OS X, or is it a reserve battery power I did not know about, or is it something completely different*

Answer (score 1):

That is your battery it self, acting up.

Following the SMC reset I would recommend a single (one time) deep discharge.

The deep discharge will reset the Battery values reported.

Just leave your computer running till it shuts down by it self due to low power.